# Why is CMake inconsistent about copying dependent DLLs to my output?

Tags: cmake, build

Let's say I have a simple project like this:

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC SDL2::SDL2 SDL2::SDL2main)
install(TARGETS test DESTINATION .)
```

If I build with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, I will find that the DLLs I depend on (`sdl2d.dll` in this case) will be copied correctly to the binary folder alongside my application.

However, in a `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` build, this doesn't seem to be the case - forcing me to add directives like this throughout my project:

```
if (WIN32)
    IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
        install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/SDL2d.dll ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zstdd.dll DESTINATION .)
    else()
        install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/SDL2.dll ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zstd.dll DESTINATION .)
    ENDIF()
    install(FILES ${install_dir}/bin/assimp-vc142-mtd.dll DESTINATION .)
endif()
```

This is especially messy now that I'm trying to integrate error-reporting tools (i.e. Sentry) that need DLL and PDB files in order to see stack traces, etc. Is there any reason this behaves as such on windows, or some way to force it to act more consistently so that my builds or install outputs are actually in a form I can consistently zip up and release?

Comment: "I will find that the DLLs I depend on (`sdl2d.dll` in this case) will be copied correctly to the binary folder alongside my application." - None of the commands called in your first snippet copies a `.dll` like `sdl2d.dll`. Probably, the dll's are initially in your build (source?) directory. BTW, which [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) do you use for your project? On Windows dll's are mostly for Visual Studio, but it is **multiconfiguration** generator so ignores `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`.

Comment: Also, **installing** into the **build** directory is weird. Relative *DESTINATION* paths for `install` command are treated relative to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, not relative to the build directory. Instead, control output directory for your executable with [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) variable and use `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target` for copy dll's into that directory.

Comment: Are you using vcpkg? It injects binary copying code.

Comment: @AlexReinking omg I thought that was just something CMake did, that would explain why I can't find any good details on why it's inconsistent lol